# c++ make macro, how to make compile time function generate

Tags: c++, templates, macros

here is example, use cpp14

After registering functions at compile time, we want to generate code that can execute the registered functions after executing them in a specific function.

```
struct Data
{
    DECLARE_DATA(Banana);
    DECLARE_DATA(Apple);
    DECLARE_DATA(Orange);
    ...
};
```

---

```
struct Data
{
    int Banana;
    int GetBanana() { return Banana; }
    int SetBanana() { // set Banana }

    int Apple;
    int GetApple() { return Apple; }
    int SetApple() { // set Apple; }

    int Orange;
    int GetOrange() { return Orange; }
    int SetOrange() { // set Orange; }
    ...

    bool Load()
    {
        SetBanana();
        SetApple();
        SetOrange();
        ...
    }
};
```

please help me....

Comment: Are you looking for constructors perhaps? It's not all too clear what you are trying to accomplish. But the solution you *wish* for is not possible. Perhaps you should ask about what this is supposed to solve, instead?

Comment: `struct Data { int Data1 = 1; int Data2 = 2;};` seems sufficient.

Comment: thanks for comment i expect code generate,

Answer (score 0):

```
#define DECLARE_DATA(name, value) int name; \
int Get##name() { return name; } \
int Set##name() { name = value; }
```

Looks like it works.

```
DECLARE_DATA(Data1, 1);
DECLARE_DATA(Data2, 2);
DECLARE_DATA(Data3, 3);
```

And here's the output of `gcc -E':

```
# 1 "t.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "t.c"

int Data1; int GetData1() { return Data1; } int SetData1() { Data1 = 1; };
int Data2; int GetData2() { return Data2; } int SetData2() { Data2 = 2; };
int Data3; int GetData3() { return Data3; } int SetData3() { Data3 = 3; };
```

However, if you need all these setters called together in another place, you're better off with a script, rather than trying to accomplish this with macros.